# Shatnez in the Kohen Gadol's clothing?

Tags: halacha, shaatnez, kohen-gadol

It seems to me that the Bigdei Kehuna included shatnez:

[Shemos 28:5 Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.28.5?ven=Metsudah_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009&lang=bi&aliyot=0#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B5%D7%9D%20%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%A7%D6%B0%D7%97%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%D6%BE%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%96%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%91%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%D6%BE%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%B5%D7%9C%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%D6%BE%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%92%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B8%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%D6%BE%D7%AA%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9C%D6%B7%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%D6%BE%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%A9%D7%81)

וְהֵם יִקְחוּ אֶת־הַזָּהָב וְאֶת־הַתְּכֵלֶת וְאֶת־הָאַרְגָּמָן וְאֶת־תּוֹלַעַת הַשָּׁנִי וְאֶת־הַשֵּׁשׁ

"They shall take the gold, the greenish-blue wool, the dark red wool the crimson wool, and the fine twined linen."

This would seem to be a conflict with the prohibition of not wearing shatnez ([See Here)](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.19?ven=Metsudah_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009&lang=bi&aliyot=0#:%7E:text=%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%D6%BE%D7%97%D6%BB%D7%A7%D6%BC%D6%B9%D7%AA%D6%B7%D7%99%20%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B9%D7%A8%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B6%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%9C%D6%B9%D7%90,shall%20not%20wear.).

Where is this further talked about and discussed, regarding the meaning of this exception and specifically, why would shatnez need to be an included element in the Kohen Gadol clothing?

Comment: https://torah.org/torah-portion/mchochmah-5776-tzav/?printversion=1#_ftn3

Comment: A positive mitzvah can override a negative one. For example bris milah must be performed on the 8th day even if it is shabbos. Likewise here it is a mitzvah for the kohen to wearing his special clothing